# Change fontsize of the risk table legend

Tags: r

```
# Create plots
library(survival)
library(survminer)
data(lung)
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
ggsurv <- ggsurvplot(fit, risk.table = TRUE,
                     tables.theme = clean_theme())
```

How do I increase the fontsize of the risk table strata?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a long time searching I still could not find a solution to this issue, yet I was able to find a suitable workaround, and eventually the answer!!!

**First, the workaround:**
Instead of using text in the table strata whose size cannot be augmented, I changed it to simply be the color of the line like so:

```
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
ggsurv <- ggsurvplot(fit, risk.table = TRUE,
                     tables.theme = clean_theme())
ggsurv$table <- ggrisktable(fit, 
                             data = severeTRdb, 
                             color = "strata", 
                             y.text = F,   ylab = "",  xlab = "",
                             tables.theme = theme_cleantable(),
)
ggsurv
```

[image]

**second - the answer:**

```
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
ggsurv <- ggsurvplot(fit, risk.table = TRUE,
                     tables.theme = clean_theme())
ggsurv$table <- ggrisktable(fit, 
                             data = severeTRdb, 
                             color = "strata", 
                             y.text = F,   ylab = "",  xlab = "",
                             tables.theme = theme_cleantable(),
                            font.tickslab = c(20, "bold")
)
ggsurv
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How is this solution using `ggplot2`? I added additional theme components which you can modify by increasing or decreasing the number assigned to size. You can also play around with the color and face components as well!

```
Library(ggplot2)
```

**Code:**

```
ggsurv$plot <- ggsurv$plot + 
theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 13, color = "black", face = "bold"),
      legend.text = element_text(size = 13, color = "black", face = "bold"),
      axis.text.x = element_text(size = 13, color = "black", face = "bold"),
      axis.text.y = element_text(size = 13, color = "black", face = "bold"),
      axis.title.x = element_text(size = 13, color = "black", face = "bold"),
      axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13, color = "black", face = "bold"))
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks but this is actually not what I was trying to do.

I was trying to increase the size of the sex=1,sex=2 part. 

To increase the numbers themselves there is actually a simpler way by using "fontsize"
like so:
ggsurv <- ggsurvplot(fit, risk.table = TRUE, fontsize = 10,
                     tables.theme = clean_theme())

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the `font.size` of each **row label** in the risk table by

```
ggsurv$table$theme$text$size <- 15
```

Comment: Any way to access this while creating the plot? Your solution works after the fact, but it's not particularly clean code.